# Collection models is empty on console.log

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a problem with collections in backbone.js, I'm doing something wrong.
This is my Model

```
var Point = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        x: 0.0,
        y: 0.0,
        z: 0.0,
    },

    validate: function(attrs) {
        if(!isNumber(attrs.x) || !isNumber(attrs.y) || !isNumber(attrs.z))
            return "Discovered NaN point";
        else return null;
    },
});
```

my collection:

```
var TrackCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Point,
});
```

And the view:

```
var TrackView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _bind('all', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.collection.models);
        return this
    },        
});
```

In my home view I do:

```
var c = new TrackCollection();
c.add({ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1});
c.add({ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1});
c.add({ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1});
var v = new TrackView({
    collection: c,
});
v.render();
```

Why the console.log(this.collection.models); in the render method returns an empty array ?
Instead if I change it into console.log(this.collection); it returns my collection object..

EDIT
Here the home view

```
window.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
    },

    events: {
        "click #makeIT": "makeIT",
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    },

    makeIT: function(e) {

        var c = new TrackCollection();
        c.add({ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1});
        c.add({ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1});
        c.add({ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1});

        var v = new TrackView({
            collection: c
        });

        v.render();
    }

});
```

If I copy the makeIT content and put it in the same file where are the model and collection it works else no

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some syntax errors in your code, for one you are missing the . for the underscore bind method (_.bind), and you have extra commas in your models views and collections.

That said it seems to work for me, here's a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feekn/) of your code (I switched the log to an alert).

Comment: The home view and the model, collection and view are in 2 different files so I tried to move `var c = new TrackCollection();
c.add({ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1});
c.add({ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1});
c.add({ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1});
var v = new TrackView({
    collection: c,
});
v.render();` in the same file and it works. But if i put it into the home view file it stop to works and alert me about zero objects instead three.

Comment: I don't see why there should be a difference if it's in a second file or not, but just to check I tested it on my local machine and it still works fine. Are you sure they are loading in the right order? Perhaps there is some other error in your second file before you create the new views that's stopping it from loading correctly.